# python pyqt4 module not opening just the last website

Tags: python, pyqt4

in this code what i want to open sites in the given list after some interval of time say 10 seconds. but this code is just opening the last website only.
so guys please help me how can i do this. i tried to use the timer but still not getting the desired results :(

```
"""
    ********************* VerySimpleWebBrowser ************************

    This is a Very Simple Web Browser implemented over Qt and QtWebKit.

    author: Juan Manuel Garcia <jmg.utn@gmail.com>

    *******************************************************************
"""

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit

class Browser(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        """
            Initialize the browser GUI and connect the events
        """

        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.resize(800,600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)

        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.mainLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.mainLayout.setMargin(1)

        self.frame = QtGui.QFrame(self.centralwidget)

        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.gridLayout.setMargin(0)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0)

        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.tb_url = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.bt_back = QtGui.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.bt_ahead = QtGui.QPushButton(self.frame)

        self.bt_back.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon().fromTheme("go-previous"))
        self.bt_ahead.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon().fromTheme("go-next"))

        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.bt_back)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.bt_ahead)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.tb_url)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)

        self.html = QtWebKit.QWebView()
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.html)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.frame)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.connect(self.tb_url, QtCore.SIGNAL("returnPressed()"), self.sparsh)

        self.connect(self.bt_back, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.html.back)
        self.connect(self.bt_ahead, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.html.forward)

        self.default_url = "http://codescience.wordpress.com/"
        self.tb_url.setText(self.default_url)
        self.browse()

    def browse(self):
        """
            Make a web browse on a specific url and show the page on the
            Webview widget.
        """

        url = self.tb_url.text() if self.tb_url.text() else self.default_url
        self.html.load(QtCore.QUrl(url))
        self.html.show()
    def sparsh(self):
        urls=["http://thapar.edu","http://yahoo.com","http://google.com"]
        for item in urls:
            i=0
            print item
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(3000, lambda: self.html.load(QtCore.QUrl(item)))
            #self.html.load(QtCore.QUrl(item))

            #self.html.load(QtCore.QUrl(item))
            self.html.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Browser()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QTimer` is in fact non-blocking which means your timers have been overlapping. Serializing your timer calls should fix this problem.

Try this ...

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit


class Browser(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        """
            Initialize the browser GUI and connect the events
        """

        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.resize(800,600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)

        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.mainLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.mainLayout.setMargin(1)

        self.frame = QtGui.QFrame(self.centralwidget)

        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.gridLayout.setMargin(0)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0)

        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.tb_url = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.bt_back = QtGui.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.bt_ahead = QtGui.QPushButton(self.frame)

        self.bt_back.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon().fromTheme("go-previous"))
        self.bt_ahead.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon().fromTheme("go-next"))

        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.bt_back)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.bt_ahead)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.tb_url)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)

        self.html = QtWebKit.QWebView()
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.html)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.frame)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.connect(self.tb_url, QtCore.SIGNAL("returnPressed()"), self.sparsh)

        self.connect(self.bt_back, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.html.back)
        self.connect(self.bt_ahead, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.html.forward)

        self.default_url = "http://codescience.wordpress.com/"
        self.tb_url.setText(self.default_url)
        self.browse()

    def browse(self):
        """
            Make a web browse on a specific url and show the page on the
            Webview widget.
        """

        url = self.tb_url.text() if self.tb_url.text() else self.default_url
        self.html.load(QtCore.QUrl(url))
        self.html.show()

    def sparsh_timer_callback (self):
        if self.sparsh_index >= len(self.sparsh_urls):
            return
        url = self.sparsh_urls[self.sparsh_index]
        self.html.load(QtCore.QUrl(url))
        self.sparsh_index += 1
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(self.sparsh_interval, self.sparsh_timer_callback)

    def sparsh(self):
        self.sparsh_urls=["http://thapar.edu","http://yahoo.com","http://google.com"]
        self.sparsh_index = 0
        self.sparsh_interval = 30000 # 30 seconds

        self.sparsh_timer_callback()
        self.html.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Browser()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I believe the QtCore.QTimer.singleshot is non blocking. So when you call your sprash method it posts 3 single shot events that essentially timeout at the same time. What you see in the gui is the last one.